# jQuery Mobile how to dynamically add html to dialog box

Tags: dialog, jquery-mobile

I am looking to open a dialog from a specific page and load dynamic data into the dialog.

On the main page I have a number of different links that when clicked provides more information on that link. All the data I have for that link is included on the main page. Somehow I would like to assign the dialog so that it is populated when the dialog opens.

I've tried something like this so far:

```
  <?php foreach($offers as $offer) : ?>
    <a href="#" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="info" data-role="button" data-desc="<?php echo $offer->{'offer_description'}; ?>" class="offer" id="offer-<?php echo $offer->{'offer_id'}; ?>"><?php echo $offer->{'offer_name'}; ?></a>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then I have an event catcher to catch the link click and then load the "data-desc" meta into the dialog but this doesn't work.

```
$('.offer').live('click', function(){
  var data = $(this).attr('data-desc');
  $("#data-desc").html(data);
  $("#dialog-offer").dialog("open");
  return false;
});


<div data-role="content" id="dialog-offer">
<p class="data-desc"></p>
</div>
```

I have been looking for an example on how to do this in jQM. This is such a basic necessity for jQM in general that I am surprised that I cannot find any examples. Could someone point me in the right direction. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of errors in your code:

1. You have given the `id="dialog-offer"` to a `<div>` with `data-role="content"`. You should wrap that `div` in another `div` with `data-role=page`
2. You don't necessarily need to use `$("#dialog-offer").dialog("open");`. Just set `<a href='#dialog-offer'>`
3. You have the wrong selector for the `html()` call. The class name of the `<p>` is what you're using with an id-style selector

I have rewritten the code and posted it here: http://jsfiddle.net/PBb3h/

Not exactly like yours, but it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it can't get the example to work in fiddle or localhost (jQM 1.0b1 and jQ 1.6.1). Those errors you spotted are a result of me getting very frustrated with this and making lots of changes but thanks none-the-less.

Comment: What happens when you run it in fiddle?

Comment: Did you happen to edit my JSFiddle? I don't know if others can edit it. Because the dialog page div id was changed from `id='dialog-offer'` to `id='#dialog-offer'`, which might have broken it. What the fiddle does now is take the stuff in `data-desc` in your anchor tag ("This is desc") and put it in the dialog. And the dialog appears correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/PBb3h/5/

Comment: No I didn't edit it, but I got it to work, thanks for the answer